# Wordpress $GLOBALS and PHP $GLOBALS

Tags: php, globals

Is the php [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) associative array over written in WordPress with the WordPress $GLOBALS? I have a piece of code that uses $GLOBALS['myvariablename'] to access a global variable. It works in php, but stops working when I bring the code to a WordPress environment.

Is there a way to use $GLOBALS associative array? Or should I absolutely declare variables global before getting them in functions and using them?

**Added Later:**

My code: http://bharath.lohray.com/sources/redditGetVotes.phps

I am trying to use the reddit API to fetch and display the popularity of my links on my wordpress blog. The global variables are for configuration information - like the reddit user name etc. I have documented my steps [in my post here](http://bharath.lohray.com/weblog/reddit-votes-in-wordpress/#.UlHd74aRAg9).

Comment: You shouldn't use $`Globals` at all, but where and how are you placing this global?

Comment: Post your code, please. `globals` are best avoided if possible, but for what it is worth I have not noticed any real issue with them if you understand how they work.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: Updated question. My Code is at http://bharath.lohray.com/sources/redditGetVotes.phps It is workign for now, but I cannot use $GLOBALS['variableName'] as an associative array.